# Using Javascript to define the html properties of a form, backgroundColor property not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to set the html properties of a form in my javascript code. All properties seem to be passed through to the web page fine (ie width and height), apart from the backgroundColor property.

```
jQuery(function () {

jQuery("#dialog-form1").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 250,
width: 400,
    backgroundColor: #e74c3c,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {},
    //close: function() {}
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: First and foremost check the error log. It's likely it'll tell you what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems, one of which is that your color needs to be enclosed in quotes so it's a valid string value (as pointed out by [freefaller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930393/freefaller)).

The second problem is that `backgroundColor` is not a valid option for the [jQueryUI Dialog](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) so you cannot pass it in and have it work. Instead, set the `backgroundColor` by chaining a call to `.css`:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#dialog-form1").css({
        "backgroundColor": "#e74c3c"
    }).dialog({
        "autoOpen": true,
            "height": 250,
            "width": 400,
            "modal ": true,
    });
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#dialog-form1").dialog({
        "autoOpen": true,
            "height": 250,
            "width": 400,
            "modal ": true,
    }).css({
        "backgroundColor": "#e74c3c"
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72bPM/

Answer (score 1):

`#e74c3c` is invalid javascript... it should be in quotes.

Replace...

```
backgroundColor: #e74c3c,
```

With...

```
backgroundColor: "#e74c3c",
```